# Having issues with keeping a new conditional rule to stay

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was having the issue of keeping the conditional formatting rule to stay. If you use the code and select a cell to color, it works. However if I want to do it for another cell, it'll erase the previous conditional formatting.

I know it has to do with `pop();` and `push();`. But I can't find a way to make a list and have the formatting be added to that list. Along with that, ensuring that if I change that same cell, the rule would be overridden for that specific cell.

I'm currently trying to do it with `rules.splice();` and I'll keep this post up to date.

The menu for the code to work

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu(' Background Color')
      .addItem('White', 'whiteBackground')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Black', 'blackBackground')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Red', 'redBackground')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Orange', 'orangeBackground')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Brown', 'brownBackground')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Yellow', 'yellowBackground')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Green', 'greenBackground')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Cyan', 'cyanBackground')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Blue', 'blueBackground')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Purple', 'purpleBackground')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Pink', 'pinkBackground')
  .addToUi();
  ui.createMenu(' Font Color')
      .addItem('White', 'whiteFont')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Black', 'blackFont')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Red', 'redFont')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Orange', 'orangeFont')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Brown', 'brownFont')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Yellow', 'yellowFont')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Green', 'greenFont')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Cyan', 'cyanFont')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Blue', 'blueFont')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Purple', 'purpleFont')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Pink', 'pinkFont')
      .addSeparator()
  .addToUi();
}
```

The formatting code

```
//
// Background colors
//

function whiteBackground() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the background color white
  var CFstore = [];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getFontColorObject();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setBackground("#ffffff")
    .setFontColor(sBG)
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function blackBackground() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the background color black
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getFontColorObject();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setFontColor(sBG)
    .setBackground("#000000")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function redBackground() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the background color red
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getFontColorObject();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setFontColor(sBG)
    .setBackground("#fc1c1c")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function orangeBackground() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the background color orange
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getFontColorObject();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setFontColor(sBG)
    .setBackground("#f78e14")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function brownBackground() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the background color brown
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getFontColorObject();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setFontColor(sBG)
    .setBackground("#593408")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function yellowBackground() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the background color yellow
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getFontColorObject();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setFontColor(sBG)
    .setBackground("#faf73c")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function greenBackground() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the background color green
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getFontColorObject();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setFontColor(sBG)
    .setBackground("#14a633")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function cyanBackground() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the background color cyan
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getFontColorObject();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setFontColor(sBG)
    .setBackground("#1095a3")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function blueBackground() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the background color blue
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getFontColorObject();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setFontColor(sBG)
    .setBackground("#3e49b0")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function purpleBackground() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the background color purple
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getFontColorObject();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setFontColor(sBG)
    .setBackground("#8c16c7")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function pinkBackground() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the background color pink
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getFontColorObject();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setFontColor(sBG)
    .setBackground("#f86efa")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

//
// Font Colors
//

function whiteFont() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the font color white
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getBackground();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setBackground(sBG)
    .setFontColor("#ffffff")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function blackFont() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the font color black
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getBackground();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setBackground(sBG)
    .setFontColor("#000000")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function redFont() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the font color white
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getBackground();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setBackground(sBG)
    .setFontColor("#fc1c1c")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function orangeFont() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the font color white
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getBackground();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setBackground(sBG)
    .setFontColor("#f78e14")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function brownFont() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the font color white
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getBackground();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setBackground(sBG)
    .setFontColor("#593408")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function yellowFont() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the font color white
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getBackground();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setBackground(sBG)
    .setFontColor("#faf73c")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function greenFont() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the font color white
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getBackground();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setBackground(sBG)
    .setFontColor("#14a633")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function cyanFont() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the font color white
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getBackground();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setBackground(sBG)
    .setFontColor("#1095a3")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function blueFont() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the font color white
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getBackground();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setBackground(sBG)
    .setFontColor("#3e49b0")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function purpleFont() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the font color white
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getBackground();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setBackground(sBG)
    .setFontColor("#8c16c7")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function pinkFont() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in the range to turn the font color white
  var sBG = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getBackground();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setBackground(sBG)
    .setFontColor("#f86efa")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.pop(rule);
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be helpful to explain the following methods first:

- [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) - removes the *last* element from an array and returns that removed element. This changes the length of the array.
- [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) - adds the specified elements to thee end of the array and returns the new length of the array. The original array is modified.
- [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) - Changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in the specified positions.

You pointed out two issues. On the one hand, your code works and correctly applies the conditional formatting when using the menu items, but on subsequent calls, previous formatting rules are lost. This is due to the `rules.pop(rule)` calls you have throughout your functions. (Also, `pop` does not accept any arguments, so normally when you need it, you just call `rules.pop()`, but it's unnecessary in this case regardless.) Removing those calls should have your conditional formatting rules persist on subsequent calls via the menu items as your calls to `rules.push(rule)` will correctly add the newest conditional formatting rules to the sheets list of conditional formatting rules.

Your other concern is regarding overwriting the conditional formatting in a range that already has formatting applied. At the moment, you are continuously adding rules to the end of the list, so if a range has multiple rules, the most recently applied rules will be overshadowed by rules that were applied earlier, as Sheets applies formatting rules in order. This does not sound like what you want. You could use `splice`, but then you would have to add some logic to determine which of the existing rules have overlapping ranges (likely via something like `rule.getRanges().forEach((r) => r.getA1Notation())`), but that may be unnecessarily complicated (especially for ranges that only partially overlap). I would recommend instead leveraging [unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift), which is the opposite of `push()` and adds the specified elements to the beginning of the array. That way if you apply conditional formatting to the same range, the newest rules will take precedent. Not 100% sure what your requirements are, so this may not be sufficient, but may be enough to get you going.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been stuck for hours.